# How to reduce cpu max speed?

Tags: power-management, cpu, temperature, cpufreq

I'm trying to improve CPU temperatures on a Dell Inspiron 7460 laptop which is a common problem with this particular machine when under reasonable stress (small chassis, badly placed vents, single cooler for both cpu and gpu). Windows allows me to simply reduce the i5 7200U max speed from 3.1GHz to 2.8GHz or 2.5GHz and although I agree it isn't the best solution, it works fine for me.

So Ubuntu 20.04.1 has any way to do the same? Also I'm new to Linux, terminal commands are usually unkown to me but I'm trying to learn and often I prefer to use them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Install the cpupower utilities `sudo apt install linux-tools-common`
This will provide `cpupower-frequency-set` utility which allows you to set the frequency as well `cpupower-frequency-set -f 2500`

There is more detail about cpupower here: https://wiki.debian.org/CpuFrequencyScaling#With_cpupower

Comment: Does not install this tool, at least, not on Mint 20.

`user@computer:~$ cpupower-frequency-set -f 2500
cpupower-frequency-set: command not found`

Answer (score 1):

`apt install cpupower-gui` will install this small tool.

[image]